# Image Orientations in SharePoint Online Carousel

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library

I have problems with several of the portrait images uploaded to a library. When I view these images inside the library, everything displays in the correct orientation, but as soon as I display the same images in a Carousel it turns them horizontally. This was a problem for me as well when I was using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. I have had to re-save each photo to fix the orientation but I do not want my users to have to do that each time they upload images. Is there a permanent fix to this?

Comment: Did you try the renditionId?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not sure how to use that attribute.

Comment: Here is the example: https://blog.mastykarz.nl/image-renditions-sharepoint-2013/